# How to draw line over a JFreeChart chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have updatable OHLCChart.
I need to draw a line over chart.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to draw a vertical or horizontal line at a given position on an axis, you can use a [ValueMarker](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/ValueMarker.html) :

```
ValueMarker marker = new ValueMarker(position);  // position is the value on the axis
marker.setPaint(Color.black);
//marker.setLabel("here"); // see JavaDoc for labels, colors, strokes

XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.addDomainMarker(marker);
```

Use `plot.addRangeMarker()` if you want to draw an horizontal line.

Comment: You can use getXYPlot() instead of getPlot() and casting.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work if you want to plot a line indicator (like a moving average for example):

```
    XYDataset dataSet = // your line dataset

    CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = (CombinedDomainXYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) plot.getSubplots().get(0);
    int dataSetIndx = plot.getDatasetCount();
    plot.setDataset(dataSetIndx, dataSet);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer lineRenderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);
    plot.setRenderer(dataSetIndx, lineRenderer);
```