# How do I draw a short line over a bar on an XYPlot using XYBarRenderer?

Tags: java, jfreechart, oxyplot

I'm currently using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), [XYPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) and [XYBarRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBarRenderer.html) to plot a horizontal bar graph. I need to draw a line on each bar in the graph that's the width of the bar, exactly like this (the red lines):

[image: Example bar graph]

Those red lines aren't exactly the same size as the blue bars, which is fine, it just can't cover the entire  graph.
I've been toying around with the answers posted to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214682/how-to-draw-line-over-a-jfreechart-chart) question and I've been trying to use XYBarRenderer.draw... and XYBarRenderer.add... to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally in JFreeChart you would create this chart using a dataset that implements the [IntervalCategoryDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/IntervalCategoryDataset.html) interface and a renderer that can render both the bars and the median markers directly from that data.  However, the main implementation of that dataset interface is a bit cumbersome to use and there is not renderer that draws exactly the visual representation you are looking for.

The next best thing (that I can think of) is to use an overlaid chart, which allows the median markers to be overlaid on top of the bars - this requires two datasets and two renderers.  Here is the result (the source code follows):

[image]

```
/* =======================
 * OverlaidChartDemo1.java
 * =======================
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Object Refinery Limited.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *   - Neither the name of the Object Refinery Limited nor the
 *     names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
 *     derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
 * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 * ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL OBJECT REFINERY LIMITED BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 * DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
 * (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
 * LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
 * ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * Original Author:  David Gilbert (for Object Refinery Limited);
 * Contributor(s):   -;
 *
 * Changes
 * -------
 * 10-Sep-2014 : Version 1 (DG);
 * 
 */

package org.jfree.chart.demo;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DatasetRenderingOrder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.IntervalBarRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.LevelRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.StandardBarPainter;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.IntervalCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;

/**
 * A sample application for the Stack Overflow question 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772655/how-do-i-draw-a-short-line-over-a-bar-on-an-xyplot-using-xybarrenderer.
 */
public class OverlaidChartDemo1 extends ApplicationFrame {

    /**
     * Creates a new demo instance.
     *
     * @param title  the frame title.
     */
    public OverlaidChartDemo1(String title) {
        super(title);
        CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset1();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, false);
        chartPanel.setFillZoomRectangle(true);
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 480));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    private static IntervalCategoryDataset createDataset1() {
        double[] start = new double[] { -4.1, -2.2, -2.1, -1.2, -0.4, 
                -0.2, -0.1, -0.15, 0, -0.1, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        double[] end = new double[] { 2.9, 3.6, 3.3, 2.5, 2.8, 2, 2.1, 2, 2, 
                1.8, 1.7, 1.8, 1.6, 1.2, 1.2 };
        DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset dataset 
                = new DefaultIntervalCategoryDataset(new double[][]{ start }, 
                        new double[][]{ end });
        dataset.setCategoryKeys(new String[] { "Dedicated Short Bias",
                "Managed Futures", "S&P 500", "Long/Short Equity", 
                "Emerging Markets", "Convertible Arbitrage", 
                "Event Driven - Multi Strategy", "Event Driven", 
                "DJ/Credit Suisse Hedge Fund Index", 
                "Event Driven - Distressed", "Multi-Strategy", "Global Macro", 
                "Fixed Income Arbitrage", "Event Driven - Risk Arbitrage",
                "Equity Market Neutral"});
        return dataset;
    }

    private static CategoryDataset createDataset2() {
        DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        dataset.addValue(-1.3, "S1", "Dedicated Short Bias");
        dataset.addValue(0.7, "S1", "Managed Futures");
        dataset.addValue(1.2, "S1", "S&P 500");
        dataset.addValue(1.1, "S1", "Long/Short Equity");
        dataset.addValue(1.4, "S1", "Emerging Markets");
        dataset.addValue(1.05, "S1", "Convertible Arbitrage");
        dataset.addValue(1.2, "S1", "Event Driven - Multi Strategy");
        dataset.addValue(1.1, "S1", "Event Driven");
        dataset.addValue(0.7, "S1", "DJ/Credit Suisse Hedge Fund Index");
        dataset.addValue(1, "S1", "Event Driven - Distressed");
        dataset.addValue(0.8, "S1", "Multi-Strategy");
        dataset.addValue(1.2, "S1", "Global Macro");
        dataset.addValue(0.8, "S1", "Fixed Income Arbitrage");
        dataset.addValue(0.5, "S1", "Event Driven - Risk Arbitrage");
        dataset.addValue(0.6, "S1", "Equity Market Neutral");
        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample chart.
     *
     * @param dataset  the dataset.
     *
     * @return The chart.
     */
    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(null);
        ValueAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Monthly Return (%)");
        IntervalBarRenderer renderer = new IntervalBarRenderer();
        renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(10, 12, 118));
        renderer.setShadowVisible(false);
        CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
        plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_LEFT);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(230, 230, 230));
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(0.5f));

        // overlay a second dataset
        plot.setDataset(1, createDataset2());
        LevelRenderer renderer2 = new LevelRenderer();
        renderer2.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(4.0f, 
                BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
        plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);

        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
                "Interquartile Range and Median: Monthly Returns", plot);
        chart.removeLegend();
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        return chart;
    }

    /**
     * Starting point for the demonstration application.
     *
     * @param args  ignored.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverlaidChartDemo1 demo = new OverlaidChartDemo1(
                "JFreeChart: OverlaidChartDemo1.java");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David!!! I will work on implementing this tomorrow. I'll get back to you then.

Comment: I just noticed I've been scrolling through your comments and code examples... wait a minute, you wrote JFreeChart?!?!?! Wow, I feel honored.

Comment: It took a little while, but I got it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, consider using `BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513). `setMeanVisible(false)` will leave the median visible by default. I haven't tried it, but `setWhiskerWidth(0)` and suitable values for each `BoxAndWhiskerItem` should suppress the whiskers and outliers.

[image]